# Add labels above Seekbars steps with different font size, vertically aligned to seekbars thumb

Tags: android, android-view, android-custom-view, android-seekbar

I would like to create a `Seekbar`, above which there will be text label on each `Seekbar` step, what it should look like is shown in below image [image: this is the Expected result]

this is the expected result, for which what i have done,

```
<RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_font_size"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtFont_size_hint"
                    style="@style/textStyle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/Aa" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layout_seekbar_interval_holder"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/txtFont_size_hint"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_16dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="5">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtSize_14"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:focusable="false"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/setting_font_text"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_14" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtSize_18"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:focusable="false"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/setting_font_text"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_18sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtSize_24"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:focusable="false"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/setting_font_text"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_24sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textSize_30"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:focusable="false"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/setting_font_text"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_30sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtSize_36"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:focusable="false"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/setting_font_text"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_36sp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <SeekBar
                    android:id="@+id/seekBarSetting_font_size"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"                       android:layout_below="@id/layout_seekbar_interval_holder"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_16dp"
                    android:max="4"
                    android:theme="@style/seekBarYelloStyle" />
            </RelativeLayout>
```

Output of this is

[image]

the Layout looks similar to what is expected but, while moving the seekbar thumb, the thumb is not vertically aligned with the `TextView`  so the problem here is the seekbar thumb is not vertically aligend with the text indicating the steps of seekBar.

I had also tried calculating the exact position of TextView by dividing the seekbars width by steps (Here we have 5 steps but first one is on 0th position so i divided the total seekbar Width by 4 and then placed each text accordingly) but didn't got the expected solution.

I am bit confused here, and want a simple solution as soon as possible.

**P.S: ScreenShot of output of view created dynamically is also attached for reference**

[image]

Comment: could your share your code how you tried to align them

Comment: its there in the layout... are you talking about the custom Component,??

Comment: Please do post an answer if you have found any solution :)

Comment: just posted an answer.. check if this helps you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

layout for this :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="android.sample.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtFont_size_hint"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Sizes"/>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:weightSum="5">

        <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="5">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtSize1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/setting_font_text"
        android:textSize="15sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtSize_18"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/setting_font_text"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtSize_24"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/setting_font_text"
        android:textSize="25sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textSize_30"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/setting_font_text"
        android:textSize="30sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtSize_36"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/setting_font_text"
        android:textSize="35sp"/>
</LinearLayout>

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBarSetting_font_size"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:max="4"/>
```

Now what i have done is aligned the width of Seekbar till the center of the last `TextView` which in this case is `txtSize_36`
and have set the ems as `android:max="4"` so there are five possible values(you can change this to as much as you want)

Code for Activity is :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
SeekBar seekBar;

private LinearLayout bar, ll;
TextView txtSize_14, txtSize_36;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarSetting_font_size);

    txtSize_14 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtSize1);
    txtSize_36 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtSize_36);
    ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll);

}
    float density;
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    ViewTreeObserver vto = ll.getViewTreeObserver();
//****old code (may not work on all orientations)****
/*vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                ll.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            } else {
                ll.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            }
            int width  = ll.getMeasuredWidth();
            int height = ll.getMeasuredHeight();

            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = seekBar.getLayoutParams();

            density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
            int newwidth = (int) (txtSize_14.getLeft() / density);
            newwidth = newwidth+ (txtSize_36.getLeft() + txtSize_36.getRight()) / 2;
            params.width = newwidth;
            seekBar.setLayoutParams(params);

        }
    });*/

    //****new code (should work on all orientations)****
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                ll.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            } else {
                ll.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            }
            seekBar.setPadding(15, 0, 15, 0);
            seekBar.setX(((txtSize_14.getLeft() + txtSize_14.getRight()) / 2) - 15);

            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = seekBar.getLayoutParams();

            int centerwidth = ((txtSize_36.getLeft() + txtSize_36.getRight()) / 2) - ((txtSize_14.getLeft() + txtSize_14.getRight()) / 2) + 15;
            params.width = centerwidth;
            seekBar.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
    });

}

}
```

Here is screenshot for reference (I have clubbed for all positions of seekbar):
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, i have spent a lot of time in this. But finally it works , +10 for your answere

Comment: Hey i found old code to be a bit more buggy so i rewrote the code please update the same

Answer (score 0):

Frankly speaking it took me a while to sort this out using XML only.
The first and last label are differently positioned than the others....
In case you will change the size of the thumb from 15dp - you must also change the margin of first and last TextView and size of Spaces (margin + Space = thumb size)

[preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUfgo.png)

```
               <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:paddingRight="0dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="0dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:paddingLeft="0dp">

                        <TextView
                            android:text="7 days"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryBackground"
                            android:gravity="left|center"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/textSize_smallest"
                            android:layout_weight="0.5"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>

                        <Space
                            android:layout_width="10dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:text="1 month"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryBackground"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/textSize_smallest"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
                            android:id="@+id/textView" />

                        <TextView
                            android:text="3 months"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryBackground"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/textSize_smallest"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:text="1 year"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryBackground"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/textSize_smallest"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:text="3 years"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryBackground"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/textSize_smallest"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"/>

                        <Space
                            android:layout_width="10dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:text="5 years"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryBackground"
                            android:gravity="right|center"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/textSize_smallest"
                            android:layout_weight="0.5"
                            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>

                    </LinearLayout>


                </RelativeLayout>
```