# JSlider like Java in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

How to I add JSlider in Android Studio?

It looks like this: [image: Java Swing JSlider]

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for a Seek Bar
See the documentation on the link below:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.html

If you want to have a custom background for your SeekBar, add a drawable, I named mine custom_progress. I have added it to SeekBar background in xml below.

**Drawable xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:shape="rectangle" >
<gradient
    android:startColor="#1F1F20"
    android:endColor="#271313"
    android:angle="0"/>
<corners
    android:radius="10dp"/>
</shape>
```

**Add the Seek Bar element to your xml**

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/simpleSeekBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_progress"
    android:max="100" />
```

**Add Java relevant code in your activity**

```
SeekBar simpleSeekBar =  findViewById(R.id.simpleSeekBar);
simpleSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean 
        fromUser) {
            //invoked if any change is made in the SeekBar.

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            //invoked at the start of user’s touch event(user started 
            //dragging)

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            //invoked at the end of user's touch event(user stopped dragging)

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO community .. there is no such thing in Android framework that provides this, and you have to build it up using [`SeekBar`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar); you may also consider building a custom `SeekBar` view.

Here is a demo of what you want to achieve by using a `LinearLayout` with a weighted inner `TextViews`, each represents a label you want to indicate for a value of the `SeekBar`

**Note:** I am using arbitrary values for the SeekBar with

- a min of 0
- a max of 100
- a step of 10

**Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekbar"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingStart="0dp"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/seekbar">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="0" />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="25" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="50" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="75" />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="100" />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Behaviour**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SeekBar seekBar = findViewById(R.id.seekbar);

        seekBar.setEnabled(true);
        seekBar.setProgress(0);
        seekBar.incrementProgressBy(10);
        seekBar.setMax(100);

        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean
                    fromUser) {

                seekBar.setProgress((progress / 10) * 10);

            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });
```

**Demo**

[image]

Also You may consider third party libraries:

- [EasySignSeekBar](https://github.com/zhou-you/EasySignSeekBar)
- [BubbleSeekBar](https://github.com/woxingxiao/BubbleSeekBar)

Also you can have a look on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41757786/add-labels-above-seekbars-steps-with-different-font-size-vertically-aligned-to) and [this](https://uxplanet.org/top-15-seekbar-and-slider-github-ui-libraries-and-components-java-swift-kotlin-d0f6a9658be3) helpful article

Comment: No, it is not helpful.

Comment: I don't want a simple seekBar, I wants in the seekBar a separate pointer (Looks like in image) instead of circular pointer, which is indicating the number below.

Comment: @SKumar so what you have tried so far to do that?, let us continue on then... have a look on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask